# Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C: when trying to use an older extension on MW 1.22.1

Tags: php, syntax-error, mediawiki

The way I have my wiki set up I need an extension that allows breadcrumbs to work and not duplicate , as well as, shrink when you go back a page. I cannot use subpage breadcrumb extensions. I would appreciate it if anyone who has a good eye for fixing code, would be able to adjust this code so that I do not get the `Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:` It occurs on line 109:

```
$m_skin =& $wgUser->getSkin();
```

Thank you in advance!

```
<?php

# The BreadCrumbs extension, an extension for providing an breadcrumbs
# navigation to users.

# @addtogroup Extensions
# @author Manuel Schneider <manuel.schneider@wikimedia.ch>
# @author Kimon Andreou
# @copyright © 2007 by Manuel Schneider, Kimon Andreou
# @licence GNU General Public Licence 2.0 or later


     if( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
  echo( "This file is an extension to the MediaWiki software and cannot be used      
 standalone.\n" );
die();
}

## Options:
# set the delimiter
$wgBreadCrumbsDelimiter = ' &gt; ';
# number of breadcrumbs to use
$wgBreadCrumbsCount = 5;

$bcBreadCrumbs = new BreadCrumbs();

$wgExtensionFunctions[] = array($bcBreadCrumbs, 'setup');
$wgHooks['UserToggles'][] = array($bcBreadCrumbs, 'toggle');

$wgExtensionCredits['parserhook'][] = array(
'name'          => 'BreadCrumbs',
'author'        => 'Kimon Andreou',
'url'           => 'http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BreadCrumbs_(Kimon)',
'description'   => "Shows a breadcrumb navigation. Based heavily on Manuel Shneider's  
extension[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BreadCrumbs]"
);

##
## Main class
class BreadCrumbs {
#constructor
function BreadCrumbs() {}

## Set Hook:
function setup() {
global $wgUser, $wgHooks;


## Showing and updating the breadcrumbs trail
# Hook when viewing article header:
$wgHooks['ArticleViewHeader'][] = array($this, 'show');

## Infrastructure
# Hook our own CSS:
$wgHooks['OutputPageParserOutput'][] = array($this, 'output');
}

#Return our new user preference (t/f toggle)
function toggle(&$arr) {
global $wgMessageCache;
#named "breadcrumb" - original, no?
$arr[] = 'breadcrumb';
$wgMessageCache->addMessage('tog-breadcrumb', 'Use breadcrumbs');
return true;
}

#Show the breadcrumbs on the page
function show( &$m_pageObj ) {
global $wgUser, $wgTitle, $wgOut, $wgBreadCrumbsDelimiter, $wgBreadCrumbsCount;

# deserialize data from session into array:
$m_BreadCrumbs = array();

#If a session doesn't already exist, create one
if( isset( $_SESSION['BreadCrumbs'] ) ) {
  $m_BreadCrumbs = $_SESSION['BreadCrumbs'];
}
else {
  if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) {
    session_start();
  }
  $_SESSION['BreadCrumbs'] = array();
}
# cache index of last element:
$m_count = count( $m_BreadCrumbs ) - 1;

# if we've got too many entries, reduce the array:
if( count( $m_BreadCrumbs ) > 0 && $m_BreadCrumbs[ $m_count ] !=
$wg Title->getPrefixedText() ) {
    # reduce the array set, remove older elements:
  $m_BreadCrumbs = array_slice( $m_BreadCrumbs, ( 1 - $wgBreadCrumbsCount ) );
  # add new page:
  array_push( $m_BreadCrumbs, $wgTitle->getPrefixedText() );
}    
else {
  array_push( $m_BreadCrumbs, $wgTitle->getPrefixedText() );
}

#if returning to a page we've already visited, reduce the array
$loc = array_search($wgTitle->getPrefixedText(), $m_BreadCrumbs);
if(($loc >= 0)) {
  #shrink array
  $m_BreadCrumbs = array_slice($m_BreadCrumbs, 0, ($loc + 1));
} 

# serialize data from array to session:
$_SESSION['BreadCrumbs'] = $m_BreadCrumbs;
# update cache:
$m_count = count( $m_BreadCrumbs ) - 1;

# acquire a skin object:
$m_skin =& $wgUser->getSkin();
# build the breadcrumbs trail:
$m_trail = "<div id=\"BreadCrumbsTrail\">&nbsp;<i>Bread crumbs:</i> ";
for( $i = 1; $i <= $m_count; $i++ ) {
  $m_trail .= $m_skin->makeLink( $m_BreadCrumbs[$i] );
  if( $i < $m_count ) $m_trail .= $wgBreadCrumbsDelimiter;
}
$m_trail .= '&nbsp;</div>';
$wgOut->addHTML( $m_trail );

# invalidate internal MediaWiki cache:
$wgTitle->invalidateCache();
$wgUser->invalidateCache();

# Return true to let the rest work:
return true;
}

## Entry point for the hook for printing the CSS:
# todo: find a better implementation
function output( &$m_pageObj, &$m_parserOutput ) {
global $wgScriptPath;

# Register CSS file for our select box:
$m_pageObj->addLink(
  array(
    'rel'   => 'stylesheet',
    'type'  => 'text/css',
    'href'  => $wgScriptPath . '/extensions/BreadCrumbs/BreadCrumbs.css'
  )
);

# Be nice:
return true;
}
}

?>'
```

---

I have removed $userName from line 1098 on Linker.php after following what Sammitch suggested:

```
public static function userLink( $userId, $userName, $altUserName = false ) {
    if ( $userId == 0 ) {
        $page = SpecialPage::getTitleFor( 'Contributions', $userName );
        if ( $altUserName === false ) {
            $altUserName = IP::prettifyIP( $userName );
        }
    } else {
        $page = Title::makeTitle( NS_USER, $userName );
    }

    return self::link(
        $page,
        htmlspecialchars( $altUserName !== false ? $altUserName : $userName ),
        array( 'class' => 'mw-userlink' )
    );
}
```

This allows the breadcrumbs to show without any errors. However, now the pages do not show in breadcrumb links. I just have > > > as though the pages go in between the arrows. Can anyone take it from here and find out how to get the pages to appear? Was removing the $userName the cause of this?

Thanks

Comment: Change it to `$m_skin = $wgUser->getSkin();`

Comment: I don't see the `->getSkin` function defined anywhere in that code, but you should configure that function to [return by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php), in which case you can probably just use Sammitch suggestion, and remove all the other 'fixes'  for this.

Comment: The ->getSkin function is line 108. I did follow what Sammitch said, as well as removed $userName from line 1098 on linker.php. But now I do not have the links for each breadcrumb, just the arrows in between.

Answer (score 0):

This extension is originally based on Breadcrumbs, which has been kept up to date: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BreadCrumbs

Looking that that code, the links are now being made by calling the linker directly:

```
$title = Title::newFromText( $m_BreadCrumbs[$j] );
$breadcrumb = Linker::link( $title, $m_BreadCrumbs[$j] );
```

So adapting that to the older code:

```
$title = Title::newFromText( $m_BreadCrumbs[$i] );
$m_trail .= Linker::link( $title, $m_BreadCrumbs[$i] );
```

Should work for you. However, that may not be the last bit of deprecated code you run into with this old extension. It might be a good idea to look at moving to the maintained BreadCrumbs extension, instead - or at least compare the code you find there and see what other changes might be needed to get this one up to speed.

Comment: THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH!  I put in:


   $title = Title::newFromText( $m_BreadCrumbs[$i] );
   $m_trail .= Linker::link( $title, $m_BreadCrumbs[$i] );

on line 113 and 114 as well as what Sammitch suggested and it works beautiful. Thank you all for your help, much appreciated.